# On Linux, some jcmd commands cannot be used

Tags: java, jvm, jcmd

some jcmd parameters are available on macos or windows, but not on Linux, such as VM.metaspace. If I want to use this parameter in Linux, what should I do?

My JDK versions are all 11

Comment: Available commands depend on the target JVM, not on the OS, nor on the jcmd version.

Answer (score 0):

The metaspace is only visible on Java 8 and above; before then, it was the permgen. You can find out what flags are available by running 'jcmd  help' for the JVM that you're talking to.